# c# Directory Services Synchronization does not return changed relationships

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I'm using C# to work with AD (Win 2012R2).
We are syncing AD users,groups and their relationship to SQL database.
Full sync works well.
But when using synchronization cookie, the relationship changes does not detected.
What may be the reason?
Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
public void DirSyncChanges(DirectoryEntry de, byte[] cookie)  
{
    DirectorySynchronization syncData = new DirectorySynchronization(cookie);
    srch = new DirectorySearcher(de)
    {
        Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))",
        SizeLimit = Int32.MaxValue,
        Tombstone = true
    };
    srch.DirectorySynchronization = syncData;
    syncData.Option = DirectorySynchronizationOptions.None;
    using(SearchResultCollection results = srch.FindAll())

    foreach (SearchResult res in results)
    {
        //results is empty. no loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please specify the DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad. Only if any of the attributes in PropertiesToLoad are updated, you will get them in delta sync.
2. As i remember the search root of DirSync must be naming context root object.
3. Better use paged search. No matter how large the value you set to SizeLimit. It will only return at most 1000 or 1500 (forgot exact number) results.

My answer is based on .NET 3.5.